# ef core db context scaffold exclude keyless entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first, ef-core-3.0

Is there any way I can exclude keyless entities from scaffolding? I have a ton of tables without a primary key. I need ef to scaffold only the tables with a primary key. If this is not supported, any way to hook this in the IDesignTimeService (like we do for pluralize/singularize entities and dbsets)/something similar. Basically I am trying to write a script that does some operations based on scaffolding. So zero manual intervention is the goal. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use EF Core Power Tools to help you choose only the tables with primary keys

Comment: @ErikEJ Yeah. thanks for the fantastic tool. I use your EF Core Power Tools only in general. However here I am trying to do an automation.  Do you know if this is possible to have CLI to generate only entities with the pk using ef 3.1?

Comment: The standard tools have a table filter

Comment: Also Power Tools have an undocumented command line interface

Comment: @ErikEJ thanks. There are numerous tables in our VERY old db, and "including" with filter is not an option. Does the power tools cli can be installed with "dotnet tool <toolname>"? or does this require the extension to be installed?

Comment: It requires the extension to be installed currently

Comment: But it is just a zip file

Comment: great. Is the Power Tool currently handle new C#'s nullable reference type as well?

Comment: No, it does not, as it is not implemented in EF Core scaffolding yet.